# Logic OR on a Bytea using GROUPBY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following Postgres table with 2 columns and the following data:

```
building    mask
blue        0001
blue        1000
blue        1100
red         0110
white       1001
white       0011
```

I want to group my buildings by color and make an OR bit by bit on my mask (bytea type) to have the following result:

```
building    mask
blue        1101
red         0110
white       1011
```

Is there a way to achieve this with a query or should I use javascript to combine after the query?

Comment: A `bit` column is a **much** better choice to store bitfields.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the aggregation function [`bit_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select building, bit_or(mask)
from t
group by building;
```

Comment: I am getting the following error. function bit_or(bytea) does not exists. To insert on the table I am using a Pentaho step that changes my binary string into a bytea.